# How to send $_FILES to $_SESSION variable properly?

Tags: php, html, file, session, session-variables

I've recently started working on an Image Upload web application in PHP, and I plan on sending an `$_FILES` variable to another form, after being taken from a previous form.

For example:
`form1` has an `<input type="file" name="image">`. After that,
`form2` takes it using `$_FILES['image']` and wants to send it to `form3` via `$_SESSION['image'] = $_FILES['image']`.

The problem is, after I try to `move_uploaded_file()` using that session variable, the file isn't moved into the directory. My `upload` directory (in which I store all the images) is empty.

That's how I tried moving the file:

```
$file = "upload/".$link.".".pathinfo($_SESSION['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['file']['tmp_name'], $file);
```

Don't worry about `$link`. That's just some "key" I use in my links (a way to auto-generate the links).

I also tried declaring another `$_FILES` variable and assigning it the value of `$_SESSION['file']`, and then use it in `move_uploaded_file()`, but still didn't work.

My question is: is it possible to correctly pass a `$_FILES` variable to `$_SESSION`? If yes, how does it come that it doesn't work in my case. What did I do wrong?

If you need more code and (or) information, feel free to leave a comment and I'll provide it to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `$_FILES` array only points to the temporary location where the file is held. It does not contain the file data directly.

After your initial request ends, that temporary file is automatically removed. So while `$_FILES` may be persisted in the session, the actual file itself is not. You'll need to save it somewhere during the initial request (using `move_uploaded_file()`), and then put a reference to the saved file into the session, instead of the raw `$_FILES` data.